# stopping and saving partial render not working

Tags: rendering, saving

I'm trying to stop and save a partial render, but have so far been unsuccessful.  Researching past questions suggests either pressing the X or ESC key, then being able to save as usual, but the image just disappears when I do this.  I can get it back by selecting "open cached render" but then it just continues with the render.  I also tried going into the UV editor after stopping, but still unable to save and no image appears there either.  Again, I am able to get it back in the UV editor by selecting as above, but again the rendering just continues.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are doing... and which version you are using? When I choose _Open Cached Render_ it does not continue rendering. When I hit `Esc` and/or close the window, I can get the unfinished render back by _Render_ > _View Render_, shortcut `F11`. I can also view it in an _Image Editor_ window when I choose "Render Result" in the _Browse Image_ list. But using _Open Cached Render_ seems to clear the cache, because afterwards the partial render is gone if I try to show "Render Result" again. Anyway, what happens when you stop rendering and hit `F11`?

Comment: By the way, did you set Blender to cache the results? From the Blender Manual: _"Note that Blender doesn’t create these cache files by default. You have to enable Cache Result in the scene’s Output options and then render it at least once."_ It does not sound as if this works with partial renders, only full renders. But this could be an option for your other question for saving renders together with the project.

Comment: Another thing, what do you mean with partial renders and why do you need them? Does it mean, not finished with all samples and still noisy? Then set a lower amount of samples and disable _Denoising_ and let it finish rendering to save it afterwards. Or do you render in tiles and only need a part of your image? Then clip the render region to a certain part of the image with `Ctrl`+`B` and let the render finish to save it afterwards.

Comment: Blender 3.6.7 as anything higher would not run on my machine.   Sorry, I'm already well beyond the issues I was encountering and would have to open and try going through your inquiries to repeat the process.  On my machine, renders take a long time, several hours.  Even keeping up with the live view is problematic.  What I ended up doing was exactly what you brought up- to just set lower amount of samples.  With most of my images, I don't see noise after 3-4 samples, but certain nodal effects will greatly increase the sample requirement. This program is taking quite  a lot to get used to.